# Why are button, input vs div, a have different width result?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the js bin http://jsbin.com/ojiJEKa/1/edit

Sorry for my stupid question, but, why `<div>` & `<a>` have different width result with `<input>` & `<button>`? Even they have same style

How to make them equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The button and input element have a `box-sizing` set to `border-box` by default. This mean the padding and border are bounded inside the defined width.

That is not the base with the a and div elements, has they have normal box-sizing property. This mean padding and border are added extra on top of the width.

To make them all the same, normalize the `box-sizing` css property.

Comment: also a `<div>` is displayed as a block and `<a>` is displayed as inline

Comment: @JayHarris Yup, but in this case they're all normalized as display block in the css.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias : yess, you are right! i;ve tried it. In your opinion, for button & button-like case, which should i choose for the box-sizing value? content-box or border-box?

Btw, thank you very much

Comment: Well, I tend to prefer putting everything border-box in a global rule (`* { box-sizing: border-box; }`). This box-model make way more sense and works way better with responsive design and % values. Note though that you need to add some browser prefix for it to work everywhere - and it works in IE >= 8!

Answer (score 1):

input and button have different box model, you can add "box-sizing:content-box" to them to reset the box model.